# How to model output pin of microcontroller in SPICE?

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, msp430, spice

I'd like to model an output pin of a microcontroller (MSP430F5xxx) in SPICE.  The datasheet contains this:

[image]

This is the I-V graph for a pin which is configured as output and set to logic low.  There is an equivalent graph for a pin set to logic high, which is almost exactly the same shape but reversed (negative large current at V=0, zero current at V=3).

Is there a good way to reproduce this in SPICE?

Bonus question: How can this be made to produce either the logic low or logic high I-V based on an input voltage corresponding to the logic level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model it with two customized (complementary) MOSFET models connected as a typical CMOS push-pull output.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE-8Q0vPUak) is a link to a video **How to model a MOSFET using a Datasheet** showing how to model a MOSFET from a datasheet. If you google you can probably find other similar tutorials on creating models.

Answer (score 2):

The push-pull output of a CMOS device is a MOSFET P-N half-bridge. Simply choose or model MOSFETs that meet the characteristics described in the datasheet.

Comment: I thought about that, but that would only have the linear part of the I-V curve.  I'm not sure what the flat part (constant I) comes from.

Comment: @AlexI It comes from the MOSFET characteristics in the saturation region.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Thank you!  I see where this curve comes from now.  I still can't figure out how to model the right MOSFETs though.  The Spice models have a ton of parameters and it is not clear how to pick them.  Any tips for a simplified model with a certain Rds(on) and saturation region?

Comment: P.S. There don't seem to be many existing discrete devices like this (and none with spice models).  For one thing, Rds(on) ~50ohm...